# NXGS warning of "export 'StateContext' was not found in '@ngxs/store'"

Tags: ngxs, nrwl-nx, nrwl

Am using NWRL NX and one of the libraries is using NXGS (3.6.2) as a shared state library for the apps.

When running an application I am getting the warning `export 'StateContext' was not found in '@ngxs/store` and referencing the actions type of StateContext e.g. example function below:

```js
@Action(FundListActions.Fetch)
fetch({ setState, getState, dispatch}: StateContext < StateModel > ) {
    const state = getState();
    setState({
        ...state,
        loaded: false,
        loading: true,
        error: null,
    });
}
```

The NXGS is running as expected, but am wondering how to fix this warning message

Comment: Try deleting your node_modules folder and running 'npm install'. I would look in the node_modules folder for @ngxs/store and see if StateContext interface is being exported.

Comment: I will check that right away

Comment: I have bunch of these warnings when I use NGXS with Angular and Storybook. I remember getting similar warnings elsewhere with my own export and I managed to fix those by switching from `interface` to `class` (or `abstract class` if you want to be more explicit). Interfaces and classes are interchangeable in TypeScript, but interfaces are stripped out of JavaScript (such concept doesn't exist there), while classes stay. So if you use interfaces you get warning. Proper fix would be probably upstream in NGXS library (since you do not control StateContext definition).

Comment: I am considering creating a bug report for this, but didn't yet get to it.

Comment: Tried a quick hack with modifying `node_modules/@ngxs/store/src/symbols.d.ts`:  changing `export interface StateContext<T> {` to `export declare class StateContext<T> {`. That did not make Warnings go away. I probably misunderstand something in this webpack compilation chain.

Comment: Any resolution on this. I'm having the same issue with StoryBook "export 'StateContext' was not found in '@ngxs/store'". There's a SB NgXs example but I don't see anything special https://www.learnstorybook.com/intro-to-storybook/angular/en/data/

Comment: Is this issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/653#issuecomment-390889335, found the following homegrown webpack plugin that fixes this error for me:

```
const ModuleDependencyWarning = require("webpack/lib/ModuleDependencyWarning")

module.exports = class IgnoreNotFoundExportPlugin {
  apply(compiler) {
    const messageRegExp = /export '.*'( \(reexported as '.*'\))? was not found in/
    function doneHook(stats) {
      stats.compilation.warnings = stats.compilation.warnings.filter(function(warn) {
        return !(warn instanceof ModuleDependencyWarning && messageRegExp.test(warn.message));
      })
    }
    if (compiler.hooks) {
      compiler.hooks.done.tap("IgnoreNotFoundExportPlugin", doneHook);
    } else {
      compiler.plugin("done", doneHook);
    }
  }
}
```

And my webpack.config.js for storybook:

```
const IgnoreNotFoundExportPlugin = require('./ignore_not_found_export_plugin');

module.exports = async({config, mode}) => {
   // ...

   config.plugins = config.plugins || [];
   config.plugins.push(new IgnoreNotFoundExportPlugin());

   return config;
}
```